# How to (re)pair existing dataset to match the highest possible correlation

Tags: r

Let's say I have a simple dataset of two continuous variables x and y with 100 values. The dataset has its descriptive statistics D1.

I would like to use R to rearrange x and y within the dataset to get the highest possible correlation, while descriptive statistics should stay the same (D1). Any ideas how to approach?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question. A sample data set would be helpful, and it's not clear what you mean by "descriptives". But wouldn't simply sorting x and y independently from low to high and then taking a correlation achieve your goal? I'm not sure why one would want to do this, however.

Comment: It was an exam question we had :-D. By descriptives I mean max, min, sd, etc. A subquestion was to produce an R solution to get a given correlation based on rearraging x and y...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just arrange `x` and `y` in ascending order:

```r
set.seed(123)

x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)

cor(x,y)
#> [1] -0.04953215

cor(x[order(x)],y[order(y)])
#> [1] 0.9830862
```

Comment: @Stanley, did this answer your question?